# Коннект к NAT шлюзу из внутренней сети

Tags: debian, iptables, nat

Установлен шлюз в Интернет на Debian. На нём же работают http и ssh серверы, которые слушают все интерфейсы.
Соединение извне, из Интернета, на внешний IP сервера, проходит замечательно.
Соединение из локалки на **внешний IP** адрес по ssh и http не работает по Connection refused.

Пожскажите пожалуйста в какую сторону смотреть для решения проблемы.
NAT работает по правилу SNAT. Пробовал через MASQUERADE - та же проблема.

Коннект на внутренний IP сервера проходит без проблем. Но на внешний удобнее - через dns имя.

```
iptables -L -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

iptables -L -n -t nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
SNAT       all  --  192.168.1.0/24       0.0.0.0/0            to:external_ip

sysctl -p | grep forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 90:e6:ba:ea:b0:8f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 195.64.199.130/27 brd 195.64.199.159 scope global eth0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::92e6:baff:feea:b08f/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:25:d3:e4:58:90 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.1.1/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global wlan0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::225:d3ff:fee4:5890/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

h:~$ ip r
default via 195.64.199.129 dev eth0 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.1 
195.64.199.128/27 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 195.64.199.130
```

Comment: можете показать `iptables -L -n` , `iptables -L -n -t nat` и `sysctl -p | grep forward` ?

Comment: Добавил. Но не могу понять зачем? NAT работает. Не работает коннект из внутренней сети к внешнему IP сервера.

Comment: А просто пинги на внешний адрес из локалки идут?

Comment: у меня есть подозрение, что того ip-адреса, который вы называете «внешним», нет ни на одном из интерфейсов шлюза. приложите к вопросу, пожалуйста, вывод команд `ip a` и `ip r`. чтобы не раскрывать анонимность, можете (аккуратно) заменить первые один-два октета *ip*-адресов на что-нибудь вымышленное.

Comment: Вывод приложил. Внешний адрес совпадает

Answer (score 1):

У вас два варианта - нарулить нужные правила NAT, либо, если у вас есть внутренний DNS, добавить на нем запись о вашем сервере, указывающую на его внутренний адрес.

Comment: То есть я не могу из внутренней сети соединиться с внешним IP NAT-сервера? Почему? Если я буду знать причину, может можно будет добавить правила для IP сервера?

Comment: Технически, вы это сделать можете, если измените правила работы NAT. Но экономичнее будет добавить запись DNS.

Comment: Хорошо, можно правила NAT нарулить. А в чем причина такого поведения? Почему я не могу соединиться с внешним IP сервера NAT?

Comment: @ddlpp я же написал - правил нет. Сервер не знает, куда девать такой чокнутый с его точки зрения трафик, поэтому он его отбрасывает.

Comment: Так я и хочу узнать почему он чекнутый. Понять в чем проблема и найти решение